# Ember not updating template when I add or remove an object from an array field in the model

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

So I've got a model that has a field of an array objects it looks like this

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    codes: attr(),  
    ...
});

and Codes looks like this 

codes: [
{
    code: stuff
    comment: stuff_1
    other_things: other_stuff
},
{
    ...
},
{
    ...
}
...
]
```

So now I have an add / remove button which has actions attached to them and this is what they do

```
add_code_input: function() {
        var codes = this.get('model.codes');
        var self = this;
        var last_code = codes[codes.length-1];

        // Cannot edit as an ember.set error is occurring
        last_code.code = 'Add new (please change)';
        last_code.code_type = "";
        last_code.comment = "";

        console.log(last_code);

        codes.push(last_code);

        this.set('model.codes', codes);


        console.log(codes);
},
remove_code_input: function() {
    var codes = this.get('model.codes');
    codes.pop();
    console.log(codes);
    this.set('model.codes', codes);
}
```

So the remove works fine but the add doesn't work.

It gives me this error when I try to update `last_code`: `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to access this property (of [object Object])`

I essentially want to add a dummy object that user can change.

So first issue is figuring out how to add dummy objects into the array properly and secondly  how to update the template as the model changes.

Comment: Adding on to the solution provided by kingpin2k, here is a jsbin to help you out http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yadariqu/1/

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `arr.pushObject(obj)` and `arr.popObject()` for manipulating an array in Ember (think of it as the setter/getter of arrays).

is codes really just `attr()` because it appears to be behaving like a DS record.

If it is a record, you just use `record.set('foo', 'bar')` if it's just a POJO you can use `Ember.set(obj, 'foo', 'bar')`.

It should be as easy as this (I'm assuming you're using and in the ObjectController here)

```
var newCode = {
  code:'foo'
};
this.get('codes').pushObject(newCode);
```

Comment: we don't have to do a set after we do a get?

Comment: Also, ember doesn't show the model is modified, even though it should.